# gradle - getWorkingBranch error on gradle-git

Tags: git, gradle

I'm trying to get branches from my git server.

my gradle file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'


buildscript {
  repositories { mavenCentral() }
  dependencies { classpath 'org.ajoberstar:gradle-git:0.6.3' }
}

import org.ajoberstar.gradle.git.tasks.*

task getBranchName(type: GitBranchList) << {
    print getWorkingBranch().name
}
```

But i get an error:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.RepositoryNotFoundException: repository not found: C:\workspace\GradleTC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My assumption is that you are not executing the task within a checked out local repository path. If you want to be explicit, you'll have to tell the task which repository your are referring to. This is done by setting the property `repoPath`. If you only want to query for the remote branches, you'll also have to set the `branchType` to `REMOTE`.

```
task getBranchName(type: GitBranchList) {
    repoPath = 'path-to-repo'
    branchType = GitBranchList.BranchType.REMOTE

    doLast {
        print getWorkingBranch().name
    }
}
```